# How to remove quick view in products category thumbnails for prestashop 1.7

Tags: themes, prestashop-1.7

How to remove quick view from product thumbnails in the category section of a prestashop 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code from *templatename*/templates/catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl

```
    <div class="highlighted-informations{if !$product.main_variants} no-variants{/if} hidden-sm-down">
  {block name='quick_view'}
    <a class="quick-view" href="#" data-link-action="quickview">
    <i class="material-icons search">&#xE8B6;</i> {l s='Quick view' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}
    </a>
  {/block}

  {block name='product_variants'}
    {if $product.main_variants}
      {include file='catalog/_partials/variant-links.tpl' variants=$product.main_variants}
    {/if}
  {/block}
</div>
```